# How to avoid "NullPointerException" when using "isEmpty()" for null Objects

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

i'm using An Object named bean with a property named val of type String.

I'm looking for a way to check if my String value isEmpty and avoid a Null PointerException.

```
if (bean.getVal().isEmpty())) { // check if my value has some text.
// do some stuff.
}
```

I hope to get the proper way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The way I see it. You have two potential NPE here. 
Bean can be null and bean.getVal() can be null

If they both can be null, I’d say you could do:

```
if (bean != null && bean.getVal() != null && bean.getVal().isEmpty()) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

If you guarantee that bean cannot be null, you can skip the first null check and use apache commons stringUtils for instance

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(bean.getVal()) { //do stuff }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use JDK8 Optional.ofNullable method

```
if(Optional.ofNullable(bean).isPresent() &&!Optional.ofNullable(bean.getValue()).isPresent()){
// do your logic
}
```